# Django: image does not display

Tags: django

I have created an admin form for the create user profile.

There there is a field for uploading the image to the server

```
avatar = models.ImageField("Profile Pic", upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
```

it works fine and can upload an image to the server. Now I want to display this image for that I have implemented some code. But it does not work.

code in views.py file

```
user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
return render_to_response('view_profile.html',{'profile':user_profile },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

code in html file

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ profile.avatar}}" alt="No Profile picture" height="420" width="420">
```

I print `{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ profile.avatar}}` then it print out put as `"/home/calcey/Documents/login/images/Nelumno_nucifera_open_flower_-_botanic_garden_adelaide2.jpg"`. It prints the correct image url but it does not display image.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: check your settings for MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL. You might have swapped their values. Read more in the docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root

Comment: use `{{ profile.avatar.url }}` instead of `{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ profile.avatar }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have forget to import the `(r'^images/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),` to the urls.py file. now it works fine